# Identifying a Returning Visitor with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I was wondering if there was a way to identify if the users on my web page is a returning user or not using the information Google Analytics already generates.

I want to display different things for returning visitors and I know Analytics already tracks this. Is there a way to tap into this information on webpage side?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason a simple cookie would not be sufficient?

Comment: That would work. But I have had analytics tracking the site for many weeks now and all those users already have the cookie. Also don't want to add more cookies and things if analytics is already doing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can read and parse Analytics cookies. Those cookies contain that data.

Presuming that you have a function `readCookie()` that returns cookie value by cookie name:

```
var visits = readCookie('__utma').split('.').pop() //returns number of visits
if(visits>1) {
    // Returning visitor
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Looks like this would work however im using the analytics.js script instead of ga.js since that is what analytics gave me when I created the profile. Analytics.js doesn't generate a __utmma cookie. Is there anyway to do this with the Analytics.js script. I suppose I can just see if the _ga cookie is there and if it is it's a returning visitor. Was just thinking there was a way to get more information.

Comment: You should google it - in general, those cookies have pretty much info - number of visits, current session pageview, traffic source, keyword, etc.
It all goes down to extracting that data from cookie values.

Comment: looks like if you're anayzing _ga cookie you're fresh out of luck. It doesn't have the visits information

Comment: This comment was originally related to the old ga.js. With analytics.js this approach is, indeed, not possible.

Answer (score -3):

New vs Returning visits are already reported on in:

Report: Audience -> Behavior -> New vs Returning (good for high level metrics)

Advanced Segments: New Visitors or Returning Visitors (good for filtering and comparing across all metrics/reports)

Comment: The question is how to use that data back on the original website.

Comment: The question was: "Is there a way to tap into this information on webpage side"